# Display Google spreadsheet data using Highcharts library

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, google-sheets

I have two columns (Date, Distance) data in a Google [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VKA3LoIG42H_13E0Id_TldXLyGIggC6jGhFYgA0rCnI/edit#gid=0). Now I want to display distance column using pie chart such that different slice of pie chart shows the sum of distances covered on different days (Sunday, ..., Saturday) of a week using [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/pie-chart) library.

Being a noob in web development, I have following queries:

1. Do I need only jQuery to plot the required data?
2. Although I figured out that I need to provide the reference of this spreadsheet in Highcharts library, but I do not know how to process this data. Do I need to process both of these columns and figure out which date corresponds to which day of the week and then compute sum? If yes, where should I write this logic?

It would be great if you can give me a dummy example to proceed further.

Comment: Are you using Highcharts could? You can plot the data through that if so, see https://www.highcharts.com/cloud/import-data/how-to-set-up-a-google-spreadsheet-file and then embed it in your site as an iframe. There's also the option to build your own, like you said, see this pen for an example https://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/AtcrE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display aggregated values for each day of the week, than this is quite easy to achieve. Data obtained from Google spreadsheet can be parsed in the `complete` function. I prepared an example for you, where pie presents sum of the data per each day of the week.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleSpreadsheetKey
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yLgbyvwh/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote for making a pie chart from two columns.  Perhaps you can adapt it to your needs.  They name of the sheet is 'PieChart' right now.

```
function makePie(dataColName,labelColName) 
{
  var dataColName = (typeof(dataColName)!='undefined')?dataColName:'Data';
  var labelColName = (typeof(labelColName)!='undefined')?labelColName:'Labels';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('PieChart');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  if(rngA[0].indexOf(dataColName)>-1 && rngA[0].indexOf(labelColName)>-1)
  {
    var datcol=rngA[0].indexOf(dataColName)+1;
    var lblcol=rngA[0].indexOf(labelColName)+1;
    var datrng=sht.getRange(2,datcol,rng.getHeight());
    var lblrng=sht.getRange(2,lblcol,rng.getHeight());
    var charts=sht.getCharts();
    if(charts)
    {
      for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++)
      {
        if(charts[i].getOptions().get('title') == sht.getName())
        {
          sht.removeChart(charts[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    var chart = sht.newChart()
                .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
                .addRange(lblrng)
                .addRange(datrng)
                .setPosition(2, rng.getLastColumn()+1, 0, 0)
                .setOption("pieHole",".3")
                .setOption("is3D", "true")
                .setOption('title',sht.getName())
                .build();
    sht.insertChart(chart);
   }
}
```